# IF condition to check if the first letter is a certain letter and a second letter exists in Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

**TLDR at the end**

I am trying to make a conversion calculator.
Basically, it gets an array of numbers along with an array of 'desired units' which either has a prefix or no prefix, and then converts the given input numbers to the desired units.

For example, it gets an array of 3 numbers along with an array of desired units for length, voltage and current:

> InputNumbers = [10000, 110, 5000] *# Assuming these are given in SI (in order: meters, volts, amperes)*
>
> DesiredUnits = [km, V, mA]   *# Can be: k (KILO), m (mili), μ (micro), M (MEGA), ...*

Generally speaking, it works fine. This is what I have written:

```
def Convert(DesiredUnits, InputNumbers ):
    for i in range (0, 2):      
        
        if (DesiredUnits[i][0]=='μ'):
            InputNumbers [i] = InputNumbers [i]*(10**6)
        
        elif (DesiredUnits[i][0]=='m'): # and (DesiredPrefix[i][1] =): 
            InputNumbers [i] = InputNumbers [i]*(10**3)
        
        elif (DesiredUnits[i][0]=='k'):
            InputNumbers [i] = InputNumbers [i]/(10**3)
        
        elif (DesiredUnits[i][0]=='M'):
            InputNumbers [i] = InputNumbers [i]/(10**6)
        
  .... ... ... .... ... ... .... ... ... .... ... ...
    return(DesiredPrefix, ArrayOfSystemNumbers)
```

You can probably tell that this checks the first letter of each of the array elements, and if it is any of the unit prefixes ('μ','m','k','M'), the corresponding multiplication or division is triggered and the number values are converted.

As you might have noticed already, there can be a **problem**. If the user sets their desired length unit to meters:

> DesiredUnits = [**'m'**, μV, kA]

, the code will confuse this with 'm' of the mili and therefore, dividing the input value of length by 10^6‼

I unsuccessfully tried making the **if** condition for the 'm' inspection so that it checks if the first letter is 'm' and a second letter exists, but I could not code this properly, as it no longer recognizes meters ('m') cause it doesn't have a second letter and therefore an error.

`elif (DesiredPrefix[i][0]=='m') and (DesiredPrefix[i][1] = .?.?.):`

**TLDR & Conclusion: Can anyone help me figure out how I can have an IF condition which checks to see if the first letter of a word is 'm' and a second letter exists that follows the m? ↓**

`if (InputArray[0]=='m') and (InputArray[1] = ???):`

Comment: You could add an `if` statement before that checks if `len(DesiredUnit[i]) == 2`, at least then your program wouldn't give an error. But I don't know of any other way that would be 'cleaner', if it exists.

Comment: I would just use a regex instead of a bunch of if-elif statements.